# Which git branch should we need to clone for kettle 7.0.0.0-25

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to debug Kettle (7.0.0.0-25) using git source code (https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle). However unable to find the branch for this corresponding jar.

How to find the branch for this kettle version?

Comment: Tag, not branch https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/tree/7.0.0.0-R

Comment: @Michael, Could you please share me where can I get this information regard branch or tag and corresponding kettle version mapping. Thanks